# Dataflow pipeline logs show connection requests from users outside of the organisation

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've created a Dataflow Pipeline in the Apache Beam Python SDK and it's working fine.

I'm watching logs and every now and then I see connection requests from random usernames at real world IPs attempting to connect in the form:

```
Invalid user <username> from <ip address> port <port>
```

The auth is working fine and these users are obviously being blocked so I'm not worried about this at all, I'm just curious as to what it actually is.

My guess is that it's bots trying to gain access to people who have set up their pipeline permissions incorrectly, but I'm unsure - does anyone know what this is being caused by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As what @PK_gcp said, these could be attempts to exploit known vulnerabilities to gain unauthorized access. It's also a good practice to review your logs periodically to stay informed about any potential security threats or patterns of activity.

Your initial guess could be correct, these could be **bots** or **automated scripts** scanning the internet for vulnerable Dataflow pipelines. The fact that the attempts are being blocked and your security measures are working is a positive sign, but it's still important to remain cautious and proactive. These automated bots are attempting to guess usernames and passwords through a **brute-force attack**. They might be trying common usernames and passwords to gain unauthorized access.

Since you've mentioned that your authentication is working properly and these attempts are being blocked, it's a good sign that your system is protected against these attacks. However, it's still important to remain vigilant and continue monitoring for any unusual or suspicious activity. If you're concerned about the frequency or volume of these connection attempts, you might consider implementing additional security measure such as **IP whitelisting**.

Comment: Thank you for the well structured and concise answer. I have to say that I'm surprised Google doesn't put more emphasis on security measures. Although the bots are being blocked, surely it wouldn't be impossible (or very difficult at all) for Google to at least send a warn log that outlines what is actually going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider checking network logs and also if you are using custom images to run workers instances having public libraries, pls consider scanning for malicious content/vulnerabilities

Comment: The only public library I am using is the Apache Beam Python SDK. If that has network vulnerabilities I would be seriously concerned. What I believe is happening is that people are trying to get in, but are getting turned away by preauth. I assume this is the case for many projects, but people don't see it because they aren't looking.

Comment: I suggest you configure this: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/routes-firewall